# How do I use dplyr to correlate each column in a for loop?

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, correlation, summarize

I have a dataframe of 19 stocks, including the S&P500 (SPX), throughout time. I want to correlate each one of these stocks with the S&P for each month (Jan-Dec), making 18 x 12 = 216 different correlations, and store these in a list called stockList.

```
> tokens
# A tibble: 366 x 21
   Month  Date                  SPX    TZERO   .....(16 more columns of stocks)......   MPS
   <dbl>  <dttm>               <dbl>   <dbl>                                           <dbl>
    1    2020-01-02           3245.50  0.95                                            176.72
    ...
    12   2020-12-31           3733.42  2.90    .....(16 more columns of stocks).....   360.73
```

Here's where my error pops up, by using the index [i], or [[i]], in the cor() function

```
stockList <- list()

for(i in 1:18) {
stockList[[i]] <- tokens %>% 
  group_by(Month) %>%
  summarize(correlation = cor(SPX, tokens[i+3], use = 'complete.obs'))
}
```

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: incompatible dimensions.
```

How do I use column indexing in the cor() function when trying to summarize? Is there an alternative way?

Comment: cor() requries matrices, and is not at al friendly towards tidy approaches.
You could try the package corrr.

Answer (score 0):

First, to recreate data like yours:

```
library(tidyquant)
# Get gamestop, apple, and S&P 500 index prices
prices <- tq_get(c("GME", "AAPL", "^GSPC"),
                 get = "stock.prices",
                 from = "2020-01-01",
                 to = "2020-12-31")

library(tidyverse)
prices_wide <- prices %>%
  select(date, close, symbol) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = symbol, values_from = close) %>%
  mutate(Month = lubridate::month(date)) %>%
  select(Month, Date = date, GME, AAPL, SPX = `^GSPC`)
```

This should look like your data:

```
> prices_wide
# A tibble: 252 x 5
   Month Date         GME  AAPL   SPX
   <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 2020-01-02  6.31  75.1 3258.
 2     1 2020-01-03  5.88  74.4 3235.
 3     1 2020-01-06  5.85  74.9 3246.
 4     1 2020-01-07  5.52  74.6 3237.
 5     1 2020-01-08  5.72  75.8 3253.
 6     1 2020-01-09  5.55  77.4 3275.
 7     1 2020-01-10  5.43  77.6 3265.
 8     1 2020-01-13  5.43  79.2 3288.
 9     1 2020-01-14  4.71  78.2 3283.
10     1 2020-01-15  4.61  77.8 3289.
# … with 242 more rows
```

Then I put that data in longer "tidy" format where each row has the stock value and the SPX value so I can compare them:

```
prices_wide %>%
  # I want every row to have month, date, and SPX
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(Month, Date, SPX),
               names_to = "symbol",
               values_to = "price") %>%
  group_by(Month, symbol) %>%
  summarize(correlation = cor(price, SPX)) %>%
  ungroup()


# A tibble: 24 x 3
   Month symbol correlation
   <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
 1     1 AAPL         0.709
 2     1 GME         -0.324
 3     2 AAPL         0.980
 4     2 GME          0.874
 5     3 AAPL         0.985
 6     3 GME         -0.177
 7     4 AAPL         0.956
 8     4 GME          0.873
 9     5 AAPL         0.792
10     5 GME         -0.435
# … with 14 more rows
```